# What does the question mark before var mean in this --> href="page.php?var=0"

Tags: php, html

What does the question mark before var mean in this --> href="page.php?var=0".
I understand that it is putting var=0 at the end of the url when this link is clicked. But what is the '?' operator?

Comment: The `?` is the separator between the url and any get arguments being passed to that url in an http request

Comment: whats it called specifically

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 denominates no special name to it. It's just a "question mark" separating path and query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an operator, it's the character that separates the query component of the url from those appearing earlier as defined by the URL grammar.

See the spec ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)) for more information; this illustrative example of URL syntax is lifted directly from there:

```
The following are two example URIs and their component parts:

     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
      |   _____________________|__
     / \ /                        \
     urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

Comment: Could to explain the fragment?

Comment: The fragment is not sent to the server. It can be used for in-page bookmarks (like scroll to point) and now are commonly used in JS applications, especially ajax apps, to select state.

Comment: @doppel: The RFC already explains it in abstract terms. In concrete terms, it's something whose significance depends entirely on the scheme part. For HTTP URLs, it's a part that does not get sent to the server but that the client (e.g. web browser) uses for its own purposes. Most of the time the fragment refers to the `id` attribute  of an HTML element, and the browser scrolls to bring that element into view after the page has loaded. But this is just one of many possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

The question mark operator marks the beginning of the query string. Php will make the name value pairs available in the $_GET array.

$_GET['var'] would have a value of '0'.

If you did href="page.php?var=0&foo=hello&bar=world

then each name/value pair separated by the ampersand "&" are available like this:

- $_GET['var']=='0'
- $_GET['foo']=='hello'
- $_GET['bar']=='world'
- $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=='var=0&foo=hello&bar=world'

Answer (score 1):

The question mark (`?`) is part of a URI; it means that there are parameters that are sent to the preceding URI. In this case, `page.php` will have access to the variable `var` from within `$_GET`. Any other variables that are to be passed along are preceded with an ampersand (`&`) instead, so you could see a URI look like this:

```
page.php?var=0&color=green
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an URI Hierarchical Identifier.
More info available on the spec here, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Answer (score 0):

That is an html string for a web address. The basics of basics for HTML. It's a variable $var with value of 0

To get this info with php use $var = $_GET['var']; (note: this does not have security, must read up on that before using properly)

Answer (score 0):

It means from this point rest of data will be sent to PHP as query (GET) data.